# Cassandra always crashing after delete table / keyspace / user / role

Tags: cassandra

OS:windows7

Cassandra:3.11.2

JDK:jdk-9.0.4

client: CassandraCSharpDriver 3.4.0.1 (or via [NoSQL Manager for Cassandra](https://www.mongodbmanager.com/cassandra))

the cassandra process always crashing when perform any delete actions:

1. delete keyspace, drop table (could be delete if checking after manually restarting);
2. delete users, roles (could not be delete at all once created)

Is anyone know the real reason and how to change the config?
Here is the error details from system.log:

ERROR [NonPeriodicTasks:1] 2018-MM-DD HH:01:17,878 LogTransaction.java:354 - Failed deletion for C:\cassandra-3.11.2\data\system_auth\resource_role_permissons_index-5f2fbdad91f13946bd25d5da3a5c35ec\mc-19-big, we'll retry after GC and on server restart
ERROR [NonPeriodicTasks:1] 2018-MM-DD HH:01:17,880 LogTransaction.java:236 - Unable to delete C:\cassandra-3.11.2\data\system_auth\resource_role_permissons_index-5f2fbdad91f13946bd25d5da3a5c35ec\mc-17-big-Data.db
java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: C:\cassandra-3.11.2\data\system_auth\resource_role_permissons_index-5f2fbdad91f13946bd25d5da3a5c35ec\mc-17-big-Data.db
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.translateToIOException(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.implDelete(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.AbstractFileSystemProvider.delete(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.delete(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.lifecycle.LogTransaction.delete(LogTransaction.java:219) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.2.jar:3.11.2]
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.lifecycle.LogTransaction$SSTableTidier.run(LogTransaction.java:345) [apache-cassandra-3.11.2.jar:3.11.2]
    at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.format.SSTableReader$GlobalTidy.tidy(SSTableReader.java:2288) [apache-cassandra-3.11.2.jar:3.11.2]
    at org.apache.cassandra.utils.concurrent.Ref$GlobalState.release(Ref.java:321) [apache-cassandra-3.11.2.jar:3.11.2]
    at org.apache.cassandra.utils.concurrent.Ref$State.release(Ref.java:220) [apache-cassandra-3.11.2.jar:3.11.2]
    at org.apache.cassandra.utils.concurrent.Ref.release(Ref.java:114) [apache-cassandra-3.11.2.jar:3.11.2]
    at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.format.SSTableReader$InstanceTidier$1.run(SSTableReader.java:2193) [apache-cassandra-3.11.2.jar:3.11.2]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source) [na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) [na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(Unknown Source) [na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [na:na]
    at org.apache.cassandra.concurrent.NamedThreadFactory.lambda$threadLocalDeallocator$0(NamedThreadFactory.java:81) [apache-cassandra-3.11.2.jar:3.11.2]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
ERROR [NonPeriodicTasks:1] 2018-MM-DD HH:01:17,880 LogTransaction.java:354 - Failed deletion for C:\cassandra-3.11.2\data\system_auth\resource_role_permissons_index-5f2fbdad91f13946bd25d5da3a5c35ec\mc-17-big, we'll retry after GC and on server restart
ERROR [MemtablePostFlush:2] 2018-MM-DD HH:01:19,378 StorageService.java:441 - Stopping native transport
INFO  [MemtablePostFlush:2] 2018-MM-DD HH:01:19,393 Server.java:176 - Stop listening for CQL clients

Comment: I think I know the reason but still could not bypass it: INFO  [Native-Transport-Requests-2] 2018-MM-DD HH:41:42,487 MigrationManager.java:519 - Drop table 'keyspace1/table1'
ERROR [MigrationStage:1] 2018-MM-DD HH:41:44,981 AbstractCommitLogSegmentManager.java:313 - Failed waiting for a forced recycle of in-use commit log segments
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: FSWriteError in C:\cassandra-3.11.2\data\commitlog\CommitLog-6-1519440054915.log (the file is not exist at all and then show exceptions above)

Comment: I got a way to bypass the cassandra crashing every time while deleting. But it seems not a good solution. conf\cassandra.yaml -> disk_failure_policy: ignore (change stop to ignore and it will not crashing)

Answer (score 0):

You have problem with file permissions for system database files.  In your log you have following:

> Unable to delete ***C:\cassandra-3.11.2\data\system_auth\resource_role_permissons_index-5f2fbdad91f13946bd25d5da3a5c35ec\mc-17-big-Data.db*** java.nio.file.***AccessDeniedException***: C:\cassandra-3.11.2\data\system_auth\resource_role_permissons_index-5f2fbdad91f13946bd25d5da3a5c35ec\mc-17-big-Data.db at

Please change permissions that given directory (`C:\cassandra-3.11.2\data`) was write accessible for user that runs Cassandra.

Comment: thanks, I'll retry. But I wonder the folder & its files are all created by the cassandra process, why it has no permissions itself?

Comment: maybe it was changed by some helper process aftewards?

Comment: unfortunately, I'm met the exact the same error again after adding "full control" to the "everyone" of the folder C:\cassandra-3.11.2\data\ and all its sub folder. I don't know how to change permission then.

Comment: I found out that it is not permission problem since the file is not exists at all. I added comment in my questions.

Comment: You didn't find why that file was removed?

Comment: I just changed: conf\cassandra.yaml -> disk_failure_policy: ignore (or best_effort) to bypass the issue.

Comment: Yes, Alex. it seems not a good solution but at least working properly. Hope anyone know the root cause why the file will disappear.